# Do I need to manually roll back a transaction if not committing changes given some conditions?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions

Example: Using transaction, and only committing if a given condition is satisfied.

```
using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    // ...
    if (modelState.IsValid) {
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

does it need to be:

```
using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    // ...
    if (modelState.IsValid) {
        transaction.Commit();
    } else {
        transaction.Rollback();
    }
}
```

or there is no need for the `else` part. What happens if I don't specify?
Any good guidelines?

Comment: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456843(v=vs.113).aspx) "Beginning a transaction requires that the underlying store connection is open. So calling Database.BeginTransaction() will open the connection if it is not already opened. If DbContextTransaction opened the connection then it will close it when Dispose() is called."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to call Rollback manually because you are using the using statement.
It is not necessary to explicitly call `Rollback`. The transaction will be rolled-back if `Commit()` has not been called.

`DbContextTransaction.Dispose` method will be called in the end of the using block. And it will automatically rollback the transaction if the transaction is not successfully committed